# Can I use HTML5 web workers in Google Apps scripts?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-worker, worker

Been looking around the docs if this is possible. Are they doable?

- http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage

Looks like they are unavaiable as trying to delcare one throws

```
ReferenceError: "Worker" is not defined. (line 17, file "code")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4674&q=worker&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) it is not possible to use the normal way, but he found a workaround using [inline workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-inlineworkers).