# How to parse URLs in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, parsing, url, google-apps-script, string-parsing

I have a GAS project and I need to parse some URLs into their `hostname` and `pathname` properties as follows.

Code.gs

```
const url = new URL( 'http://www.example.com/cats', );
const { hostname,  pathname, } = url;
```

Here are some docs on the above URL constructor method. [[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) | [[2]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)

The above code produces the following error.

Error message:

> ReferenceError: URL is not defined (line 64, file "Code")

What am I missing? How can I parse my URLs using GAS?

Comment: what is your requirement exactly? your syntax is clearly incorrect but don't know what's the value of each variable like link, hostname, pathname? the URL syntax should const url = new URL(link);

Comment: @Kedar: If you are referring to the trailing comma when you cite my syntax, you should be aware that trailing commas have been supported since ECMAScript 5 for object literals and ECMAScript 2017 for function parameters. [They are the preferred syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas) as it makes version control diffs cleaner and less trouble editing code because you can add new properties without modifying previous lines that already use a trailing comma.

Comment: No, I wasn't referring to trailing comma, that's fine in GAS but not the use of URL as it is not valid ECMA/script standard but part of web api. The same reason, why you can't do console.log in GAS. Instead add fetch for URI.js in .gs and then... const url = URI( 'http://www.example.com/cats', );

Comment: @Kedar: If it's [different from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62125000), please consider adding an answer that explains how you would recommend to add fetch for URI.js in .gs

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://googleappscripting.com/working-with-urls/) explains how to implement the [URI.js library](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) into a Google Apps Script project.

##### URIjs.gs

```
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/URI.js/1.19.11/URI.min.js').getContentText());

// Get the URL protocol (eg. 'https' or 'http')
function urlProtocol(url){
  return URI(url).protocol()
}
  
// Get the URL hostname (eg. 'googleappscripting.com')
function urlHostname(url){
  return URI(url).hostname()
}

// Get the whole URL path (eg. '/some/directory/filename.png')
function urlPath(url){
  return URI(url).path()
}

// Get the URL directory (eg. '/some/directory')
function urlDirectory(url){
  return URI(url).directory()
}
    
// Get the URL file name (eg. 'filename.png')
function urlFilename(url){
  return URI(url).filename()
}

// Get the URL query string (eg. 'this=1&that=2')
// If a query string parameter is provided as the second argument
// then the function will return the value of that parameter
function urlQuery(url,param){
  if (param !== undefined){
    var queryMap = URI(url).query(true);
    return queryMap[param]
  }
  return URI(url).query()
}

// Get the URL hash (eg. '#section-two')
function urlHash(url){
  return URI(url).hash()
}

// Check to see if a URL is a fully qualified URL
function urlIsUrl(url){
  return URI(url).is('url')
}

// Check to see if a URL is a fully qualified IP Address
function urlIsIp(url){
    return URI(url).is('ip')
}


// Test function to ensure that each of the above functions do what they are supposed to do.
function testURI() {

  var testUrl = 'https://googleappscripting.com/some/test/page.html?this-is=helpful&it=works#rad';  
  var funcTests = [
    urlProtocol,
    urlHostname,
    urlDirectory,
    urlPath,
    urlFilename,
    urlQuery,
    urlHash,
    urlIsUrl,
    urlIsIp
  ]
  
  // Check that each function returns the expected value
  funcTests.forEach(function(test){
    Logger.log(test(testUrl))
  });
  
  // Extra check to see that the urlQuery function works with a query parameter argument
  Logger.log(urlQuery(testUrl,'it'));

}
```

Then in my code, as follows:

##### Code.gs

```
const hostname = URIjs.urlHostname( 'http://www.example.com/cats', );
```

Comment: 2023 update: rawgit.com is discontinued. cdnjs.cloudflare.com can be used as a drop-in replacement: `eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/URI.js/1.19.11/URI.min.js').getContentText());`

Answer (score 1):

The [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) is not part of ECMAScript, it's part of a [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API), more specifically of [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API). Google Apps Script doesn't support web APIsm by default.

---

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime

> **Modern ECMAScript syntax**
>
> You can use modern ECMAScript syntax in scripts that are powered by the V8 runtime. This syntax includes `let`, `const`, and many other popular features.

Related

- [Can I use HTML5 web workers in Google Apps scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28429130/1595451)

Comment: Downvoted, because this answer only says what the person is doing wrong, and doesn't answer the question: `How to parse URLs in Google Apps Script?`